# Storing posts (image, caption) in Firebase database with auto increment Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store user posts in my firebase data like the following:

[image]

I have successfully stored each image in storage with the following code:

```
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(postImage!)
        // guard for user id
        guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        let photosRef = storage.reference().child("posts")
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(uid)")

        photoRef.child("\(imageName)").put(data!, metadata: nil){(metaData,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("there was an error")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else{
                // store downloadURL
                let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

                let values = ["uid": uid, "caption": caption, "download_url": downloadURL]

                // store downloadURL at database
                let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                // store values in posts/post_1 (post_1..post_2 etc)
            }

        }
```

However, I'm having trouble storing the downloadURL (values array) in my posts database because I can't figure out how to have an incremental value for `post 1` `post 2` `post 3` etc etc

Is there a better way to store the posts in the `posts` database without needing incremental values?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an entire section in the [Firebase documentation on storing lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). You'll note that this section does not use indices like you're trying to use, for several good reasons. If you'd like to learn more about those reasons, read this [classic blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thanks for the blog post -- I read through it earlier but will do again to learn Firebase's best practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to store incremental values - it all depends on how you want the values stored and how you will be retrieving and using them.

The general process is to create parent nodes using childByAutoId - Firebase generates the distinct node names for you.

```
let ref = rootNode.childByAutoid()
ref.setValue("my value")
```

This will result in nodes with a Firebase generated key

```
root_node
   -Ynaosdokasodkpasd: "my Value"
```

That being said, it's hard to order them in a meaningful way, so you may want to add nodes that will enable you to specify the order

```
let ref = rootNode.childByAutoid()
let dict = ["text": "my value", timeStamp: "20161207131600"]
ref.setValue(dict)
```

which results in

```
-Ynaosdokasodkpasd
    text: "my value"
    timeStamp: "20161207131600"
```

you can then use the timeStamp to order your data in Firebase queries.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using childByAutoid, like you suggested.